# Enviar *ngIf al componente padre mostrar u ocultar columna en tabla de angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Quisiera saber como puedo realizar esto:

Tengo un filtro en un componente hijo, que tiene unos checkbox lo que debe de hacer es al yo seleccionarlo mostrarme u ocultarme una columna en una tabla, como hago para poder comunicar esto al componente padre, mi código esta así:

ComponenteHijo.ts

```
@Output() check = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
ocultarTelefono: boolean
ocultarNombre: boolean
```

ComponenteHijo.html

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="!ocultarTelefono" (change)="ocultarTelefono = !ocultarTelefono"/>
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="!ocultarNombre" (change)="ocultarNombre = !ocultarNombre"/>
```

y en el componente padre en el html tengo lo siguiente:

```
<componente-hijo></componente-hijo>

    <thead>
            <tr>
                 <th *ngIf='!ocultarTelefono'>Telefono</th>
                 <th *ngIf='!ocultarNombre'>Nombre</th>
           </tr>
    </thead>
 <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td *ngIf='!ocultarTelefono'>858585858</td>
            <td *ngIf='!ocultarNombre'>Lorem ipsum</td>
          </tr>
 <tbody>
```

Cuando tenia todo el codigo en el componente padre funcionaba normal, pero ahora necesito pasar todo al componente hijo y que se siga ocultando o mostrando las columnas si esta o no checked el input.
no se si exista otra manera

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar lo siguiente:

En tu componente hijo:

```
@Output() ocultarTelefono = new EventEmmiter<boolean>()
```

En el `html` de el padre:

```
<componente-hijo (ocultarTelefono)="ocultarTelefono = $event"></componente-hijo>
```

`$event` esta reservado para obtener el resultado emitido y lo que hacemos es asignarselo a la variable que queremos revisar en el componente padre.

Comment: Al hacerlo así el (change)="ocultarTelefono = !ocultarTelefono" me arroja error que una expresión booleana no puede ser asignada a un tipo EventEmmiter<boolean>

Comment: No estoy usando la propiedad `(change)`, estoy usando el `Output`. Revisa [este ejemplo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nchsex?file=src/app/padre/padre.component.html) para que te des una idea.